# i18n json file generator (form table/CSV file)

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I am using i18n with vueJS, using this great plugin https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

So my file looks like  this:

```
export default {
    "en": {
        "menu": {
            "home": "Home"
            }
        }
    "fr": {
        "menu": {
            "home": "Accueil"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't find it very convenient as the website becomes quite big and there will be quite a lot of languages. It's always a pain to write in each of the languages, particularly when there are different people writing on it.

I would like to know if there is an existing solution to generate this file, from a table (an existing interface?), excel, or from a CSV file. It would be a two ways binding.

I have tried to find this on the internet but couldn't find anything interesting.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution in my repo [i18n-generator](https://github.com/hueitan/i18n-generator) solves your problem. Yes, you can edit the file in CSV type, but unfortunately, two ways binding doesn't support.